# VAIO Battery checker caution error

Tags: windows-7, laptop, battery, sony-vaio

I [downloaded](http://www.sony-asia.com/support/product/vpcs116fg) and Installed VAIO Battery checker a few minutes ago, now this error appears every now and then and I am unable to do anything. I don't know how to uninstall it, I didn't find it among installed programs in Control Panel. I did remove and reinsert the battery, but to no avail.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Click on Start, type ‘msconfig’ and then select the ‘Startup Tab’,
> 2. Deselect the "ISB Utility" from the startup.
> 3. Restart your computer.

[Reference](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/vaio-vgn-tx651p-battery-message-wrong-battery-or/93fd88e7-3c80-46c8-9822-9e03e93a1a50)